# Had so issue with jest react-native and bugsnag

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, bugsnag

I tried run Jest unit tests on React-Native with Bugsnag, but I got error:

```
 The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.
    
    ReferenceError: window is not defined
      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import Bugsnag from '@bugsnag/react-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution which is working for me:

we need to add mock bugsnag interceptor to jestSetupFile.js

```
jest.mock('@bugsnag/react-native', () => ({
  use(plugin) {
    const boundary = plugin.init();
    // we don't need the error boundary to swallow the errors, we want jest see them and fail the test
    delete boundary.prototype.componentDidCatch;
    return boundary;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with just mocking Bugsnag: `jest.mock("@bugsnag/react-native", () => jest.fn());`

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was:

```
jest.mock('@bugsnag/react-native', () => {
  return {
    isStarted: () => false,
    start: () => false,
    getPlugin: () => {
      return {
        createErrorBoundary:
          () =>
          ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) =>
            children,
      };
    },
  };
});
```